# Understanding map, flatmap and option in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand how to use functional programming concepts(map, flatmap, filter ..) in scala in the following case. Basically I am trying to filter Inner1 with `id` and read `value` here. Could you please how can I read v(value) if I have a reference to `out` object

```
final case class Inner2(v:Option[String])
final case class Inner1(id: String,inner2: Seq[Inner2])
final case class Out(inner1: Option[Seq[Inner1]])
val inner2 = Inner2(Some("value"))
val inner11 = Inner1("id",List(inner2))
val inner12 = Inner1("id2",List())
val out = Out(Some(List(inner11,inner12)))
```

I know the following code is not correct but I put it here to show what is trying to be done.

```
out.inner1
  .flatMap(_.headOption)
  .filter(_.id=="id")
  .map(_.inner2)
  .flatMap(_.headOption)
  .flatMap(_.v)
```

Comment: What exactly do you wanted to do? Probably the error is that you are mixing **Option** and **Seq / List**. Your class hierarchy is a little bit weird, since a collection can be empty, an `Collection[Seq[T]]` usually is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```scala
out.inner1
  .flatMap {
    _.withFilter(_.id == "id").flatMap {
      _.inner2.flatMap {
        _.v
      }
    }.headOption
  }
//println gives `Some(value)`
```

If you want to extract the Option value, you may use `.getOrElse("")` in the end

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is pretty close to what you can do - I would give your objects proper names and proper types, and then your code starts to make more sense.

I just removed the `Option` from the `Outer` class (as an empty `Seq` is also `None`):

```
final case class Out(inner1: Seq[Inner1])
```

Then the code gets this:

```
out.inner1
   .filter(_.id=="id")
   .flatMap(_.inner2)
   .flatMap(_.v.toSeq) // > List(value)
   .headOption         // > Some(value)
```

With proper names it could look like:

```
repo.users // Out -> Repo - Inner1 > User
   .filter(_.id=="id")
   .flatMap(_.addresses) // Inner2 -> Address
   .flatMap(_.maybeStreet.toSeq) // value -> optional street
   .headOption
```